# Using strcmp with string arrays

Tags: c++, loops, initialization, c-strings, strcmp

I'm making a program of a quiz but I'm having a problem with arrays of strings and the function strcmp

I think I might have to use pointers but I do not know which to assign as a pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main(){
char question1[5][1000]={"Question #1\n\nWhat is the formula for the area of a square?\n\nA.) Area = (Side)(Side)\nB.) Area = Side + Side\nC.) Area = Base + Height\nD.) Area = (pi)(Radius)(Radius)\nAnswer: ",
"Question #2\n\nWhat is the perimeter of a rectangle with length = 4 and width =8?\n\nA.) Perimeter = 4 + 8 = 12 units\nB.) Perimeter = (4)(8) = 32 units\nC.) Perimeter = 2(4) + 2(8) = 24 units\nD.) Perimeter = [2(4)][2(8)] = 128 units\nAnswer: ",
"Question #3\n\nWhat is the circumference of a Circle with Diameter = 10 units?\n\nA.) Circumference = (pi)(5)(5) = 78.5 units\nB.) Circumference = 2(pi)(5) = 31.41 units\nC.) Circumference = (pi)(10)(10) = 314 units\nD.) Circumference = 2(pi)(10) = 62.8 units\nAnswer:",
"Question #4\n\nWhat is the measurement for the side of a square with Perimeter = 80?\n\nA.) 20 units\nB.) 80 units\nC.) 40 units\nD.) 50 units\nAnswer: ",
"Question 5\n\nWhat is the radius of a circle with area = 64pi square units?\n\nA.) 2pi units\nB.) 4pi units\nC.) 6pi units\nD.) 8pi units\nAnswer: "};
char answer1[5][2]={"A","C","B","A","D"};
char answer;
int score,i;
for(i=1;i<5;i++){
cout<<question1[i];
cin>>answer;
if(strcmp(answer,answer1[i])==0)
{
    score++;
}
}
cout<<"Your score is "<<score;
}
```

Comment: You also need to consider the case of the user input because "a" is not equal to "A". Use toupper(answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`answer` is a *single character* and not a string. You can't use it as a string when passing it to functions expecting string. The call to `strcmp` should have caused the compiler to emit a warning about this.

Compare the character directly, as e.g. `answer == answer1[i][0]`.

Or change the type to a string (`std::string` preferably, otherwise an array of `char`).

---

On an unrelated note, you don't initialize the variable `score`. That means its value will be *indeterminate* and using it (like in `score++`) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to explicitly initialize it:

```
int score = 0, i;
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `answer` is declared as a one-byte character.

```
char answer;
```

It can not store a string.

So you may not use the standard function `strcmp` with an object of the type `char`.

You could just write

```
if ( answer == answer1[i][0] )
```

But it is better to declare the array `answer1` as

```
const char answer1[] = { "ACBAD" };
```

or

```
const char *answer1 = { "ACBAD" };
```

and use the following if statement

```
if ( answer == answer1[i] )
```

Pay attention to that the variable score is not initialized

```
int score,i;
```

You have to initialize it. And moreover the index in the loop should start from 0.

```
int score = 0;
for( int i = 0;i < 5; i++ ){
//...
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `5`. You can introduce a named constant. For example

```
const size_t N = 5;
char question1[N][1000] = { /*...*/ };
//...
for( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well dear OP allow me to be blunt. That is not C++, that is a C code with iostreams. Also first question was never printed, other errors spotted etc.

None of which is a problem, **if** you are willing to learn. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZkX6cigRtZPVnPPU) is a standard C++ working version. Please compare to your code and study it.

```
// clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

 using namespace std;
 // required for sv literal 
 using namespace std::literals;

 // compile time std array of string literals
 // each transformed to string_veiw's
 // by using the `sv` std defined literal
 constexpr array questions {
  "Question #1\n\nWhat is the formula for the area of a square?\n\nA.) Area = (Side)(Side)\nB.) Area = Side + Side\nC.) Area = Base + Height\nD.) Area = (pi)(Radius)(Radius)\nAnswer: "sv,
  "Question #2\n\nWhat is the perimeter of a rectangle with length = 4 and width =8?\n\nA.) Perimeter = 4 + 8 = 12 units\nB.) Perimeter = (4)(8) = 32 units\nC.) Perimeter = 2(4) + 2(8) = 24 units\nD.) Perimeter = [2(4)][2(8)] = 128 units\nAnswer: "sv,
  "Question #3\n\nWhat is the circumference of a Circle with Diameter = 10 units?\n\nA.) Circumference = (pi)(5)(5) = 78.5 units\nB.) Circumference = 2(pi)(5) = 31.41 units\nC.) Circumference = (pi)(10)(10) = 314 units\nD.) Circumference = 2(pi)(10) = 62.8 units\nAnswer:"sv,
  "Question #4\n\nWhat is the measurement for the side of a square with Perimeter = 80?\n\nA.) 20 units\nB.) 80 units\nC.) 40 units\nD.) 50 units\nAnswer: "sv,
  "Question #5\n\nWhat is the radius of a circle with area = 64pi square units?\n\nA.) 2pi units\nB.) 4pi units\nC.) 6pi units\nD.) 8pi units\nAnswer: "sv
   };

   // same compile time structure as questions
   // but for answers
   constexpr array answers {"A"sv,"C"sv,"B"sv,"A"sv,"D"sv};

  int main()
 {
   char answer {};
   int score{} ;
   // answer counter starts from 0
   size_t j = 0;
    // standard C++ 'sequence' loop
    for ( auto & question : questions ) {
      cout << question;
      cin >> answer;
         if( answer == answers.at[j][0] ) score++;
         j++ ;
    }
      cout <<"Your score is "<< score;
      return 42 ;
  }
```

One might even claim standard C++ is simple, looking at this. One just has to use it.

**APPENDIX**

Better design would be to create and operate on a single structure, that will keep both answers and questions together. Some lateral thinking always helps.

```
// clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility> // std::pair

using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;

constexpr std::array a_q_pairs {
    pair{ 'A', "Question #1\n\nWhat is the formula for the area of a square?\n\nA.) Area = (Side)(Side)\nB.) Area = Side + Side\nC.) Area = Base + Height\nD.) Area = (pi)(Radius)(Radius)\nAnswer: "sv } ,
    pair{ 'C', "Question #2\n\nWhat is the perimeter of a rectangle with length = 4 and width =8?\n\nA.) Perimeter = 4 + 8 = 12 units\nB.) Perimeter = (4)(8) = 32 units\nC.) Perimeter = 2(4) + 2(8) = 24 units\nD.) Perimeter = [2(4)][2(8)] = 128 units\nAnswer: "sv},
    pair{ 'B', "Question #3\n\nWhat is the circumference of a Circle with Diameter = 10 units?\n\nA.) Circumference = (pi)(5)(5) = 78.5 units\nB.) Circumference = 2(pi)(5) = 31.41 units\nC.) Circumference = (pi)(10)(10) = 314 units\nD.) Circumference = 2(pi)(10) = 62.8 units\nAnswer:"sv},
    pair{ 'A', "Question #4\n\nWhat is the measurement for the side of a square with Perimeter = 80?\n\nA.) 20 units\nB.) 80 units\nC.) 40 units\nD.) 50 units\nAnswer: "sv},
    pair{ 'D', "Question 5\n\nWhat is the radius of a circle with area = 64pi square units?\n\nA.) 2pi units\nB.) 4pi units\nC.) 6pi units\nD.) 8pi units\nAnswer: "sv }
 };

int main()
{
 char user_answer {};
 int score{} ;

 // single loop
 // requires no change on adding/removing answers/questions pairs
 // no need to code index checking
 for ( auto & a_and_q : a_q_pairs ) 
 {
    auto & answer = a_and_q.first ; // char
    auto & question = a_and_q.second ; // string_view
    cout << question ;
    cin >> user_answer;
    if( user_answer == answer ) score++;
  }
   cout <<"Your score is "<< score;
   return 42 ;
```

}

Well designed data structure and a simple algorithm operating on it. Perhaps I will dust off that [Niklaus Wirth book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs)?

Obligatory [WandBox is here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cj2aH6rFpltEF9aJ).

Comment: To "use `at` for bounds checking" you must handle the resulting exception. I would instead suggest a `static_assert` that questions and answers have the same size.

Comment: @MSalters dully noted, I was thinking to **not**  have two structures but one, keeping both answers and questions in it, and thus avoid the need for index checking ...although I think I might have already overloaded the OP's plate with the new stuff to learn.